# Extracting a sequence of integers which give max in each step in mathematica

Tags: integer, wolfram-mathematica, sequence

I would like to write a program in Mathematica and looking for the integer n such that the following definition holds for any 1 < m < n

f(n)/f(m)>1+log(n/m)/(log n loglog m)

where f(n) is number of divisors of n. (and also count the number of resulting set)

I wrote the following code, but the problem is that when it finds first "j1" in the next step for it looks for the value "j2" for which f(j2)/f(j1)>1+log(j2/j1)/(log j2 log log j1)
but I want that it find "j2" such that

f(j2)/f(j)>1+log(j2/j)/(log j2 log log j)

for all j which are j1 <= j < j2

**Note**: In the following example k[*] is a special and known sub sequence of integers.

Thanks

```
i = 20;

count = 0;

list = {i};

For[j = i, j <= 500, j++,

    If[ f[k[j]]/f[k[i]] > 1 + Log[k[j]/k[i]]/(Log[k[j]] Log[Log[k[i]]]), i = j; 
        AppendTo[list, i];
        count = count + 1
    ]
];

list

Print["count= ", count]
```

Comment: Is the Log[k[j]/k[j]] (which probably is supposed to be Log[k[j]/k[i]]) only a typo here, or also in your real code?

Comment: Do I miss something, or is your idea OK? Will the first 'j2' that satisfies the condition with respect to 'j1' automatically fulfill the condition to all 'j' in-between? If not, your first 'j1' is probably incorrect already. You need a second loop to run 'i' to 'j'.

Comment: assume we start with k[20], then when we reach to the first k[j] such that not only f[k[j]]/f[k[20]]>(1+Log[k[j]/k[20]]/(Log[k[j]]Log[Log[k[20]]])), also f[k[j]]/f[k[i]]>(1+Log[k[j]/k[i]]/(Log[k[j]]Log[Log[k[i]]])), for all i such that 20<i<j

Comment: @mikuszefski, assume we start with k[20], then when we reach to the first k[j] such that not only f[k[j]]/f[k[20]]>(1+Log[k[j]/k[20]]/(Log[k[j]]Log[Log[k[20]]])), also f[k[j]]/f[k[i]]>(1+Log[k[j]/k[i]]/(Log[k[j]]Log[Log[k[i]]])), for all i such that 20<i<j.